# Javascript error only in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I get this javascript error in IE 8

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected
```

The error point to this line

```
/*@cc_on(function(a,b){function r(a){var b=-1;while(++b<f)a.createElement(e[b])}if(!window.attachEvent||!b.createStyleSheet||!function(){var a=document.createElement("div");return a.innerHTML="<elem></elem>",a.childNodes.length!==1}())return;a.iepp=a.iepp||{};var c=a.iepp,d=c.html5elements||"abbr|article|aside|audio|canvas|datalist|details|figcaption|figure|footer|header|hgroup|mark|meter|nav|output|progress|section|subline|summary|time|video",e=d.split("|"),f=e.length,g=new RegExp("(^|\\s)("+d+")","gi"),h=new RegExp("<(/*)("+d+")","gi"),i=/^\s*[\{\}]\s*$/,j=new RegExp("(^|[^\\n]*?\\s)("+d+")([^\\n]*)({[\\n\\w\\W]*?})","gi"),k=b.createDocumentFragment(),l=b.documentElement,m=b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode,n=b.createElement("body"),o=b.createElement("style"),p=/print|all/,q;c.getCSS=function(a,b){try{if(a+""===undefined)return""}catch(d){return""}var e=-1,f=a.length,g,h=[];while(++e<f){g=a[e];if(g.disabled)continue;b=g.media||b,p.test(b)&&h.push(c.getCSS(g.imports,b),g.cssText),b="all"}return h.join("")},c.parseCSS=function(a){var b=[],c;while((c=j.exec(a))!=null)b.push(((i.exec(c[1])?"\n":c[1])+c[2]+c[3]).replace(g,"$1.iepp-$2")+c[4]);return b.join("\n")},c.writeHTML=function(){var a=-1;q=q||b.body;while(++a<f){var c=b.getElementsByTagName(e[a]),d=c.length,g=-1;while(++g<d)c[g].className.indexOf("iepp-")<0&&(c[g].className+=" iepp-"+e[a])}k.appendChild(q),l.appendChild(n),n.className=q.className,n.id=q.id,n.innerHTML=q.innerHTML.replace(h,"<$1font")},c._beforePrint=function(){if(c.disablePP)return;o.styleSheet.cssText=c.parseCSS(c.getCSS(b.styleSheets,"all")),c.writeHTML()},c.restoreHTML=function(){if(c.disablePP)return;n.swapNode(q)},c._afterPrint=function(){c.restoreHTML(),o.styleSheet.cssText=""},r(b),r(k);if(c.disablePP)return;m.insertBefore(o,m.firstChild),o.media="print",o.className="iepp-printshim",a.attachEvent("onbeforeprint",c._beforePrint),a.attachEvent("onafterprint",c._afterPrint)})(this,document)@*/
```

However all that had been commented. Some ajax calls aren't being executed(again only in ie). Is it because of this error or something else? Thanks

Comment: You may need to do more research yourself on this one and provide more detail. That's obfuscated code, so without knowing where it came from, what file the error occurred in, etc, I don't think any normal human can help you :) If you're using a library, try to find an uncompressed version and replicate the error, then at least it won't be all on one line.

Comment: Thanks. I will look for an uncompressed version. But my point was the whole thing is commented right, then why is ie saying there are errors in this line. No such problem in other browsers.

Comment: Great question, inquiring minds want to know. Post your code and maybe we can help you get to the bottom of this mystery :)  And keep in mind that IE is a nightmare when it comes to cross-browser problems. What works in Chrome/FF/Safari doesn't always work in IE :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*@cc_on is IE's very own conditional comment - it is executed in IE and ignored in other browsers. If you cannot find uncompressed version of script, you can yust insert line breaks to narrow problematic code.